# SQL: If field is empty, return empty string, otherwise cast as number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, casting

I'm running SQL Server 2008 (otherwise I would use Try_Parse) and I need to cast a field as a number in cases where it is non-empty. If the field is empty, an empty string or NULL should be returned. I would prefer if the field was stored as a number in the database, but I have no control over that at this time.

Here is what I have tried:

`SELECT CASE WHEN AccountNumber='' THEN '' ELSE CAST(AccountNumber AS bigint) END AS AccountNumber FROM Accounts`

OR

`SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(AccountNumber AS bigint)=0 THEN '' ELSE CAST(AccountNumber AS bigint) END AS AccountNumber FROM Accounts`

But both of these bring back 0 for empty account numbers. I feel that this should be possible but I am going crazy trying to figure it out! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can't select both numbers and empty strings into the same column, because they are incompatible types. That's why the empty strings get converted automatically to 0. NULL should work, however.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN AccountNumber='' OR AccountNumber IS NULL THEN NULL
  ELSE CAST(AccountNumber AS bigint) END AS AccountNumber
FROM Accounts
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution I can hope for! I knew I was close. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ISNUMERIC function:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(AccountNumber) = 1 THEN CAST(AccountNumber AS BIGINT) ELSE NULL END
FROM Accounts
```